# Troubleshooting ogr2ogr error when loading shapefiles into PostGIS: Error 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

I am trying to get familiar with PostGIS. I have been trying to work through the PostGIS tutorial and following the instructions closely but they aren't working for me and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

For a while I was trying to input the following code almost verbatim from PostGIS website to load a shapefile into the database:

```
ogr2ogr \
  -nln nyc_census_blocks_2000 \
  -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI \
  -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom \
  -lco FID=gid \
  -lco PRECISION=NO \
  Pg:'dbname=nyc host=localhost user=postgis port=5432' \
  nyc_census_blocks_2000.shp
```

That kept throwing the error "Unable to open datasource `nyc_census_blocks_2000.shp' with the following drivers." And it goes on to list some drivers.

After checking permissions and my bash environment and not being able to identify an obvious issue, I started looking for an alternative way to input the same code and ended up with this:

```
ogr2ogr "PostgreSQL" "PG:host=localhost user=postgres dbname=nyc password=******" "nyc_census_blocks_2000.shp" -nln nyc_census_blocks_2000 -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=gid -lco PRECISION=NO
```

At least that started throwing a *different* error, "Error 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer 'nyc_census_blocks_2000.shp'!"

Should I reinstall my GDAL package?

Comment: Does `ogrinfo nyc_census_blocks_2000.shp` find your source data?

Comment: Have you tried supplying the full path to the shapefile. Like `ogr2ogr -lco SCHEMA=public -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost dbname=testdb user=postgres  password=qwerty" "/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/ak_riks1.shp" -nln "aka34324kak1"`

Comment: @BERA Thanks, yes I have tried using the full file path and it throws the same error: "Error 1: Couldn't fetch requested layer..." I have checked the file path and it doesn't contain any spaces or unusable characters.

Comment: How did it go with ogrinfo?